# add ng-dbclick for options of select in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, html-select

i have a `<select>` tag and use `ng-options` to bind options of `select`.
my question is how to add `ng-dbclick` to each option of `select`

here is my code

```
<select  size="4"  ng-model="pattern" ng-options="p.name  for p in patterns | filter:obj">

</select>
```

Comment: ng-dbclick is an event that fires when you double click on an element

[ng-dbclick](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngDblclick)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think that you can add an event handler to an option of a select box in js so this won't work in angular either.

What you can do is add the `ng-dblclick` to the select element and then get the selected option which will also be the doubleclicked one.

This would be the value of your `pattern` model.

```
<select  size="4"  ng-model="pattern" ng-dblclick="doYourStuff()" ng-options="p.name  for p in patterns | filter:obj">

</select>
```

Have a look at [**this plunker for a demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/lxgQ7IwvgjKe6Bq3m5Hc?p=preview).